# Comparar datatable con lista

Tags: c#, comparaciones

tengo que comparar los registros de un `DataTable` con los objetos de una lista, el `datatable`, pongamos que solo tiene una columna "**codigo**", el objeto articulo, tiene varios campos, **id**, **nombre**, **descripcion**, **precio** y **stock**.
Quisiera obtener los objetos con mismo **id** comunes.
A lo más que he llegado es a:

```
var result = allp.Select(x => x.id).Except(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(y => y["codigo"]));
```

Pero es obvio que algo no hago bien porque no obtengo el resultado deseado.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar el **operador Intersect** que devuelve una lista de los elementos que hay en común entre las dos colecciones, el **operador Except** que es el que estás poniendo es una resta de conjuntos, es decir muestra los elementos que están en la primera colección que no están en la segunda, atendiendo al código que pones de ejemplo te quedaría como:

```
var result = allp.Select(x => x.id).Intersect(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(y => y["codigo"]));
```

Para lograr todo lo anterior debes hacer uso de **Linq** y poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```